# continue statement in pl/SQl?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘CONTINUE’ keyword in Oracle 10g PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177752/continue-keyword-in-oracle-10g-pl-sql)

I am Using Oracle 9i and I want to use continue statement or its equivalent in PL/SQL. So is there any keyword called "continue" in oracle 9i. If not, please let me know the solution for this.

Comment: It seems this questions is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177752/continue-keyword-in-oracle-10g-pl-sql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CONTINUE statement was added in Oracle 11G, it is not available in prior versions.  A solution would be to use GOTO:

```
loop
   if something then
      goto continue_label;
   end if;
   ...
   <<continue_label>> null;
end loop;
```